# Count Left users in binary PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, mysqli-multi-query

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
    `user_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
    `user_name` char(150) NOT NULL,
    `parent_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
    `leg` enum('l','r') NOT NULL,
    `status` enum('unactive','active','block') NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

`parent_id` is the id where user join 
leg is the position of the user join l=left r=right.

Example:

[image]

Its two leg binary. 
I want to count all users in left side of top user. As in image
2nd level user use 1 level user id as parent ID.

Please help me

Comment: I don't think this can be solved with a single query, but I think it's relatively easy with a recursive function. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please use punctuation in your text (commas, periods, capitalization etc...). Your writing is difficult to understand (at least for me).

Answer (score 0):

At first, this looks like a problem to solve with recursion; but with a few changes to your database schema it could be done with a single query. As far as database queries go, it's not the most efficient way to do it, but it still beats recursion.

The basis for this answer comes from a [ruby on rails gem](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry)

The idea is to use an `ancestry` field instead of `parent_id`. The ancestry field contains a reference to all of a record's parents. So for the following tree:

```
          1
    2           3
 4     5     6     7
8 9  10 11 12 13 14 15
```

The "ancestry" field would look like this:

```
Id  Ancestry
--------------
1   null or ''
2   '1L'
3   '1R'
4   '2L 1L'
5   '2R 1L'
6   '3L 1R'
7   '3R 1R'
8   '4L 2L 1L'
9   '4R 2L 1L'
10  '5L 2R 1L'
11  '5R 2R 1L'
12  '6L 3L 1R'
13  '6R 3L 1R'
14  '7L 3R 1R'
15  '7R 3R 1R'
```

So now, getting the count and/or all the children on the left of ID 1 is simple:

`SELECT COUNT(id) AS child_count FROM users WHERE ancestry LIKE '%1L%'`

`SELECT * FROM users WHERE ancestry LIKE '%1L%'`

To get the users on the left of ID 2:

`SELECT * FROM users WHERE ancestry LIKE '%2L%'`

Want the children on the right of ID 1?

`SELECT * FROM users WHERE ancestry LIKE '%1R%'`

---

Edit

Just realized that the fuzzy like will get some bad results once `ancestry` numbers get into the double digits. To solve this, use some delimiter in front of each ancestor, ie,

```
Id  Ancestry
--------------
1   null or ''
2   '_1L'
3   '_1R'
4   '_2L_1L'
5   '_2R_1L'
6   '_3L_1R'
7   '_3R_1R'
8   '_4L_2L_1L'
9   '_4R_2L_1L'
10  '_5L_2R_1L'
11  '_5R_2R_1L'
12  '_6L_3L_1R'
13  '_6R_3L_1R'
14  '_7L_3R_1R'
15  '_7R_3R_1R'
```

and then include that delimiter in the query:

`SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users WHERE ancestry LIKE '%_1L%'`

Comment: Cleaner than this is the [Nested Set Model](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model) where each node has a left and right ID and my descendants' IDs are always between mine ... which is where I initially thought was where you were going with this answer.  Nested sets allow a simple integer range query to resolve any arbitrary depth below a given node.

Comment: Thanks i got big help with your table structure. my counting issue has been resolve using this completely. can you also tell me to display the tree using https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/orgchart  with this structure

Comment: I don't have any experience with the orgchart, but it looks like you would simply use php to iterate through the `data.addRows([` so that the javascript could then build the chart.  Sorry I can't help you there.  If my answer to this post helped you, please consider marking the answer accordingly.